# How to fix offsetWidth of undefined error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using [awesomplete autocomplete plugin](http://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete) with thumbnail and I have index.html and I've `<input id="myinput">` element but on my laoyut.html if I didn't put `<input id="myinput">` then js give me a this erros 
`jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined`

and my question is what should I do to fix it ?

```js
var input = document.getElementById("myinput");

// Show label but insert value into the input:
new Awesomplete(input, {
  list: [{
      label: "<img src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRUxdD-Q4nIx3uIg9jBCe1oT5a9MHuWY5_pW4FoZSU-nQd1Y_WJPQ'/> Faceboock",
      value: "https://www.facebook.com/"
    },
    {
      label: "<img src='https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/dota2.gamepedia.com/thumb/2/25/Pounce_icon.png/16px-Pounce_icon.png?version=77c984fc4a9c8ca491ead081322fa738'/> Youtube",
      value: "https://www.youtube.com/"
    },
    {
      label: "China",
      value: "CN"
    },
    {
      label: "United States",
      value: "US"
    }
  ]
});

// You can search for a better version
$(document).find('.awesomplete').on('click', function(e) {
  if ($('#myinput').val())
    window.location = $('#myinput').val();
  //console.log($('#myinput').val());
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesomplete/1.1.1/awesomplete.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input id="myinput" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/awesomplete/1.1.1/awesomplete.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first check if #myinput is available in the html dom, then you can use the value of it.

```
var input = $("#myinput");
if (input.size() > 0) {
    window.location = input.val();
}
```

I asume that there will be one div with this specific id. In that case, you can use

```
if (input.size() === 1) {
```

So in short, you can replace

```
$(document).find('.awesomplete').on('click', function(e) {
  if ($('#myinput').val())
    window.location = $('#myinput').val();
  //console.log($('#myinput').val());
});
```

with

```
$(document).find('.awesomplete').on('click', function(e) {
  var input = $('#myinput');
  if (input.size() === 1) {
    window.location = input.val();
  }
});
```

Comment: yes but I'm still getting this error and new error too Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null

Comment: I updated the answer, let me know if this works for you

Comment: maybe this error about this line `var input = document.getElementById("myinput");`

Comment: Hi, I need insight in your whole project to debug these errors.